# Global variable creation order in Java

Tags: java

Is it guaranteed that below instances are created in order? For example, can we assume B is always created before E?

```
public class Example {
  public static final Integer A = new Integer(1);
  public static final Integer B = new Integer(2);
  public static final Integer C = new Integer(3);
  public static final Integer D = new Integer(4);
  public static final Integer E = new Integer(5);
  public static final Integer F = new Integer(6);
}
```

Comment: That isn't even valid code.

Comment: Oops mistake in edit, didn't notice this they were assigned to `Integer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as statements are confirmed to execute in order by sequence, it is most likely that the instances/objects will be created in order OR will be allocated memory in order.

Also,your code is not even valid as pointed by `Kevin Krumwiede`, you are missing datatype declaration for all the variables/references...

```
public static final Integer A = new Integer(1);
public static final Integer B = new Integer(2);
public static final Integer C = new Integer(3);
public static final Integer D = new Integer(4);
public static final Integer E = new Integer(5);
public static final Integer F = new Integer(6);
```

Answer (score 1):

Although your code won't compile but yes it will created in order(*if rectified properly*) since the compiler will go line by line and execute and create each instance.

Correct code:

```
public static final Integer A = new Integer(1);
public static final Integer B = new Integer(2);
public static final Integer C = new Integer(3);
public static final Integer D = new Integer(4);
public static final Integer E = new Integer(5);
public static final Integer F = new Integer(6);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are guaranteed to run in order. You can have static fields that are created based on the values of previously defined static fields in the same value.

```
public static final Integer A = new Integer(1);
public static final Integer B = A+A;
```

Others have already pointed out that you forgot to declare the type of the field, but you should also know that because of autoboxing you do not need to use "new Integer()". The following code is equivalent:

```
public static final Integer A = 1;
public static final Integer B = 2;
public static final Integer C = 3;
public static final Integer D = 4;
public static final Integer E = 5;
public static final Integer F = 6;
```

If you are using Eclipse, make sure that you tell it not to reorder fields as part of code cleanup.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are initialized in order upon loading the class. You can refer to the [JLS 12.4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4) for details. Specifically from step 9 of this procedure,

> Next, execute either the class variable initializers and static initializers of the class, or the field initializers of the interface, in textual order, as though they were a single block.